# set acl permission for tabs in sales order view

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, acl

I need to set ACL permission for the tabs under sales order view

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately those tabs are not real links with their own controller, but all loaded at once. So the usual `_isAllowed()` method in controllers cannot be used here.

But you can make the tabs use the ACL with a few rewrites:

- Rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Invoices` and override the method `canShowTab()` as follows:

  ```
  public function canShowTab()
  {
      return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/invoice');
  }
  ```
- do the same for `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Creditmemos` and the other tab classes, and replace `sales/invoice` with `sales/creditmemo` etc.

Now users that are not allowed to access invoices won't see the invoices tab on the order page anymore either.

Comment: Yes, it worked.